# Finding ID from different Tweet URL

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x, beautifulsoup

I am fetching the id, from tweet URL,

```
url=["https://twitter.com/bbcworldservice/status/1240666763425128449?ref_src=twsrc%5Etfw", 
    "https://twitter.com/BILOSuperSaver/status/1240578769255051264/photo/1", 
   "https://twitter.com/Rangoli_A/status/1227792415676780545"]

for i in url:
   tid=i.split('/')[-1]
   print(tid)
```

Output, I am getting is

```
1240666763425128449?ref_src=twsrc%5Etfw
1
1227792415676780545
```

I know, it's a basic method to get the ID, I have also tried the other methods and the result is the same

**Expected output**

```
1240666763425128449
1240578769255051264
1227792415676780545
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the fact that the ID comes right after the word "status/", what your program does is splitting each string by "/" and taking the last item in that list, but the ID does not always come last - as seen in first URL in your list:

```
"https://twitter.com/bbcworldservice/status/1240666763425128449?ref_src=twsrc%5Etfw"
```

From the examples in your list, I will make an assumption that the ID comes after the word "status" and split by this word, taking the second item (as we want to discard what comes before). Then, we will split again using "/" and taking the first item (as we want to discard what comes after):

```
for i in url:
    tid = i.split('status/')[1].split('/')[0].split('?')[0]
    print(tid)
```